# Highcharts column chart stacked not showing all the values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a column chart with Highcharts and I want to stack the values by time. So the xAxis is of type datetime. This is my config (omitting the less important configuration options):

```
var chartOptions = {
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    chart: { 
      type: 'column',
      zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [
        {
          name: "test",
          type: 'column',
          data: [[1432400400000, 2], [1432486800000, 5], [1432573200000, 7]]
        },
        {
          name: "test_1",
          type: 'column',
          data: [[1432400400000, 2], [1432486800000, 5], [1432573201000, 9]]
        }
    ],
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
        }
      }
    }
}
```

If the date sent is identical then the stacking is working right but if there is a second of difference, then it's not stacking well, like the third column in the following image:

[image]

It's a bit weird because it's showing the numbers. Is there any option for increasing the stacking range to minimum one second or something like that?

Fiddle: [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/cncs0khh/)

Comment: I don't think that for now it is possible to have stacking on some range, for now the logic behind stacking is to stack the values of the same x parameters. You can ask for this option on userVoice if you think it is good idea to have this in highcharts: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Comment: I think that it can be an interesting feature in order to improve the user experience when the users are seeing the charts. I am going to suggest it, thanks!

Comment: I would suggest that you aggregate your data at whatever level of time makes sense to achieve what you need - whether by minute, hour, day, week, etc. Makes more sense to me to clean the data then to ask the chart to figure it out :)